# How to test for exception that is caught inside method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4

So I wrote the temporary method that looks like this:

```
public void tempMethod(String invalidCode) {
        try {
            long temp = Long.valueOf(invalidCode);
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.err.println("Wrong code format, code must contains numbers only. Your wrong code: " + invalidCode);
        }
    }
```

I want to write test for it with JUnit 4.10. The thing is solutions I found on web are not able to test it. I haven't really wrote any tests untill now so the question might be stupid.

Here is what I tried:

```
@Test(expected = NumberFormatException.class)
    public void testEx() {
        testInstance.tempMethod("asd");
    }
```

And that says test failed, but exception message appears on output. I tried the test with use of

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException expectedEx = ExpectedException.none();
```

but this doesn't work for that case either.

Is there any option to check this method without changing `tempMethod` body?

Comment: A test compares something with its specification.  You have not told us the specification for this code, so it is impossible for someone to tell you how to test it.

Comment: How come two other guys get it but u didn't?

Comment: They guessed. But your question is unclear.

Comment: Still do not get what is unclear to you, I gave you temp method instead of wall of code. It's part that I was wondering about if it's testable or not. I put there how I was trying to test it. Asked politely and mentioned that I am new to testing. What specification of code are you looking for? It's pretty clear what this part of code is about in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method does not throw an exception, that's why the test fail.

You see, when an exception is thrown **and caught** inside the method, then you have in effect handled the exception: the programmer decided that this exception is not important and is just printing it, without throwing it further or stopping execution.

So the only way to test this is to check the standard error stream to see if the appropriate string was written to it. The exception is gone as soon as the `catch` block is closed.

Comment: Testing error stream is the idea I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

as you pointed out yourself, the test fails because you are not throwing the exception, you caught it inside the method.

Anyway your method should either return something or have some side effect (quite probably a different one when it completes successfully and when it catches an exception), otherwise it isn't doing anything. That is what you should test.

Comment: Now I get it, it's bit confusing for me atm, have to get used to it. Thanks for reply